# CosmosDB Mongo Database Request Saving Issue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb

I have quite large request to save and it is really necessary to save it. I have read across the web and according to documentation the request size should be between 2-4 MB and when I save it and get error below:

> "Mongo Error: Request size is too large "

it contains lots of text, and images that required for the user to upload so the document gets really big. How can I save large request data in the cosmosDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official document for Cosmos DB Limitation:

> There are no restrictions on the item payloads like number of
>   properties and nesting depth, except for the length restrictions on
>   partition key and id values, and the overall size restriction of 2 MB

[image]

And the max request size is 2MB,response size is 4MB.([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits))

If your data is 2MB+, you could follow the strategy in this [blog](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/overview-of-azure-cosmos-db/): Cosmos DB document size is limited to 2 MB and is not supposed to be used for content storage. For larger payload storage, use Azure Blob Storage instead.

Or you could consider using [MongoDB Atlas on Azure](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/microsoft-azure/) if you'd like full MongoDB feature support.